# Implicit differentiation: $x\cos (4x+3y)=y\sin x$

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, derivatives, implicit-differentiation

> $$x\cos (4x+3y)=y\sin x$$

I have been stuck on this problem for the longest. I have the answer but I don't know how to get to it. I have used the product and chain rule on both sides. I keep getting this:

$$\frac{\cos(4x+3y)-4x\sin(4x+3y)-y\cos x}{\sin x}$$

Here is the answer:

$$\frac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dx} = \frac{\cos (4x+3y)-y\cos x-4x\sin (4x+3y)}{\sin x + 3x\sin (4x+3y)}$$

Comment: You'll have to use the product rule on each side.

Comment: Write $F(x,y)$ as ($lhs-rhs$). Compute the partial derivatives of $F(x,y)$ with respect to $x$ and then to $y$ and compute the classical ratio from total differentiation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\sin(4x+3y)+x\cos(4x+3y)(4+3dy/dx)=(dy/dx)\cos x -y\sin x$

$\sin(4x+3y)+4x\cos(4x+3y)+3(dy/dx)\cos(4x+3y)=(dy/dx)\cos x -y\sin x$

$\sin(4x+3y)+4x\cos(4x+3y)+y\sin x=(dy/dx)\cos x + 3(dy/dx)\cos(4x+3y)$

$\sin(4x+3y)+4x\cos(4x+3y)+y\sin x=(dy/dx)(\cos x + 3\cos(4x+3y))$

Comment: I don't see any $5y$ in the question --- was there an edit?

Comment: Yes, it is my mkistake. It is 3. I corrected it.